# Printing values from an array only once

Tags: php, mysql, printing, unique, distinct

I want to use an if statement that when it matches a string in the database, it prints out a message. But, in the database, if there is more than one count of the string then it prints it out multiple times. Does anyone know how to make sure it only prints once? Many thanks. My code is:

```
    if ($value == 'America') 
    {
    echo "Welcome";
    }
```

Comment: What is your data stucture? What query are you using to pull the data?

Comment: u should have to use distinct in ur query

Comment: Would the use of `break;` be suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you have given one solution would be:

```
welcome_displayed = false;
if (welcome_displayed and $value == 'America') 
{
    echo "Welcome";
    welcome_displayed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're in a loop. If so, I would use the `break` construct:

```
<?php

$array = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow');

foreach ($array as $color) {
  if ($color == 'blue') {
    print "We found a match.";
    break;
  }
}
```

If you're simply trying to write a query that only gets 1 match, use the DISTINCT keyword or LIMIT the number of results, or something like that. If you update your question I can update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine any matches into an array and then use 'array_unique' to only get the distinct items.

```
// DEFAULTS 
$matched_items = array();
$values = array('Denver', 'ABQ', '1234', 'asdfa', 'America', 'osproqr', 'America', 'iowrenvoiw', 'America');

// LOOP THROUGH EACH VALUE AND COMPARE IT AGAINST THE NEEDLE
foreach ($values AS $value) {
    if ($value == 'America') {
        $matched_items[] = $value;
    }
}

// PRINT OUT ONLY THE UNIQUE ITEMS
print_r(array_unique($matched_items));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use SELECT DISTINCT on the columns you want to select.

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT /*table column*/ FROM /*TABLE NAME*/ WHERE /*column name*/ = America "
```

This will select only one row WHERE a column = America.

Comment: this suggestion not answer

Comment: While that would indeed result in a single row in the set returned from the database, we don't know if that would remove other information required in the query.

Comment: DISTINCT used with any column value

Comment: @user3227914 you haven't provided enough information to confirm if this would work or not.

Comment: Yep DISTINCT did exactly what I wanted, thank you so much for help guys

Comment: OK it would be great if you could vote up my comment and select it as the answer.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? `DISTINCT` is indeed the right solution to the problem. It's usually better to filter data SQL-side than to do it PHP-side.